# How to print a particular numeric value from a variable content in python

Tags: python-3.x, object-slicing

When I run this code:

```
from luno_python.client import Client
import json

c = Client(api_key_id='<api_id>', api_key_secret='<api_secret>')
try:
  bal = c.get_balances(assets='NGN')
  print(bal)
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
```

I get this output:

> {'balance': [{'account_id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'asset': 'NGN', 'balance': '0.000274', 'reserved': '0.00', 'unconfirmed': '0.00'}]}
> >>>

What I need is anytime I run:

```
>>>print(bal)
```

Let me get only this portion as output:

> 0.000274
> {'balance': [{'account_id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'asset': 'NGN', 'balance': '`0.000274`', 'reserved': '0.00', 'unconfirmed': '0.00'}]}

I need only the highlighted portion above.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: Yes I have tried something like `bal['balance']` and it removed the first balance in my output. Certainly not reflecting on the portion I need

Comment: But closer to it, no? So now you have a list, learn how to use lists. Continue until you have what you do want. Please read e.g. https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if what you get is a `dict`, but seems like it. Anyways, you just need to get the values by its keys as following:

```
bal['balance'][0]['balance']
```

or much safer to avoid using another `try` and `exception` :

```
bal.get('balance',[{'balance':'when bal is empty'}])[0].get('balance')
```

Comment: This worked great!!! +1 for putting me through in a more concise way. But one more thing I how do I round it off to the nearest 2 decimal place like `0.00` because I tried using it in my code and it threw an error that the amount specified contains decimal, I don't know how to avoid that

Comment: Can you share us what you've tried and what you wanna get ? It'll help us to understand much better :)

Comment: I have solved the issue by doing `balance = float(bal.get('balance',[{'balance':'when bal is empty'}])[0].get('balance')[:4])` and the issue was solved. Thanks a lot for your candid help. I really appreciate.